# Matcher Find Infinite Loop

Tags: java, string, pattern-matching, match

I'm trying to replace certain words in a long string. What happens is some words stay the same and some change. The words that don't change seem to get the `matcher` stuck in an infinite loop as it keeps trying to do the same action on words that are meant to stay the same. Below is an example similar to mine - I couldn't put the exact code that I'm using because it's far more detailed and would take up too much space I'm afraid.

```
public String test() {
    String temp = "<p><img src=\"logo.jpg\"/></p>\n<p>CANT TOUCH THIS!</p>";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(<p(\\s.+)?>(.+)?</p>)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(temp);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(temp);
    int start;
    int end;
    String match;

    while (matcher.find()) {
        start = matcher.start();
        end = matcher.end();
        match = temp.substring(start, end);
        stringBuilder.replace(start, end, changeWords(match));
        temp = stringBuilder.toString();
        matcher = pattern.matcher(temp);
        System.out.println("This is the word I'm getting stuck on: " + match);
    }
    return temp;
}

public String changeWords(String words) {
    return "<p><img src=\"logo.jpg\"/></p>";
}
```

Any suggestions as to why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `Matcher` wrong. Your while loop reads:

```
while (matcher.find()) {
     start = matcher.start();
     end = matcher.end();
     match = temp.substring(start, end);
     stringBuilder.replace(start, end, changeWords(match));
     temp = stringBuilder.toString();
     matcher = pattern.matcher(temp);
}
```

it should just be:

```
matcher.replaceAll(temp, "new text");
```

No "while" loop, it is unnecessary. A matcher *will not* replace text it does not match and it will do the right job with regards to not matching twice at the same place etc -- no need to spoonfeed it.

What is more, your regex can do without the capturing parens. And if you only want to replace "words" (regexes have no notion of words), add word anchors around the text to be matched:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\btext\\b");
```

Comment: Problem is that I need the `start` and `end` variables. They contain indexes that get passed in other areas of the code. If I use `replaceAll` then I have no access to those parameters anymore.

Comment: You did not say that in the initial question, in your code extract I only see them as being used for replacement indices in the `StringBuilder` (which the matcher itself can do)

Answer (score 2):

You reinitialize the matcher in the loop.

Remove the `matcher = pattern.matcher(temp);`  instruction in your `while` loop and you should not be stuck any more.

Comment: It does resolve the infinite loop but if I take out that line then the `matcher` doesn't update to use the new `temp` string so it misplaces the replacements because it gets the `start` and `end` indexes wrong. (It's identifying matches & indexes from the old `temp` string not the new one)

Comment: Your code is still wrong for other reasons you need to find out. This just solved the "infinite loop" you asked for.

Comment: This solution works but it breaks something else in order to work which means I have to revert to an infinite loop, so it's not resolved yet...

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to match "text" word and again replacing that word either with "text" (if condition in changeWord()) or "new text" (else in changeWord()). That whay it's causing infinite loop.

Comment: I know. The example I placed above has that on purpose to illustrate the fact that some words might remain the same but that the `matcher` should move onto the next match instead of idling on the same one.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `Matcher` at all? You don't need regex to replace words, just use `replace()`:

```
input.replace("oldtext", "newtext"); // replace all occurrences of old with new
```

Comment: It's to find the indexes of the words it's replacing

Comment: However, this will also replace `iamoldtext` with `newtext`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it simply by adding this line:

```
if (!match.equals(changeWords(match))) {
     matcher = pattern.matcher(temp);
}
```